# Finding the equipotential surface of a system of two unequal oppositely charged point charges

Tags: electrostatics, point-particles

We have a system of two unequal opposite point charges, of which $q_2$ is smaller and $d$ is the distance between charges. There is an equipotential spherical surface of potential $V=0$ that encloses a charge of lesser absolute value. The task is to find parameters of that spherical surface, or more precisely circle, since the system is of course illustrated in two dimensions.

[image: Physical system described in a text]

First we take into consideration arbitrary point $M(x,y)$ where $V=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\left(\frac{q_1}{r_1}+\frac{q_2}{r_2}\right)$. If we use $V=0$ it's easy to obtain $\frac{r_1}{r_2}=-\frac{q_1}{q_2}=k$ where $k$ is coeficcient of proportionality.

From the illustration, we can see that $r_1^2=(d-x)^2+y^2$ and $r_2^2=x^2+y^2$. Then we have $\frac{r_1^2}{r_2^2}=k^2=\frac{(d-x)^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ from which $\left(x+\frac{d}{k^2-1}\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac{kd}{k^2-1}\right)^2$ is obtained. This equation is the equation of a circle shown in the illustration with coordinates of the circle center $x_0=-\frac{d}{k^2-1}$, ($|x_0|=\frac{d}{k^2-1}$), and $y_0=0$. The radius of the circle (equipotential sphere) is $R=\frac{kd}{k^2-1}=k|x_0|$. **How is this equation of a circle derived?**

For $q_1$ we have $q_1=2Q$
and for $q_2$ we have $q_2=−Q$ which gives $k=2$, but I don't see how that can help. Also, this problem uses the method of image charges because it comes after the lesson in my textbook where the method of image charges is explained.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking how equation $\left(x+\frac{d}{k^2-1}\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac{kd}{k^2-1}\right)^2$ is obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a bit of algebra.  Starting from
$$ k^2 = ((d-x)^2 + y^2) / (x^2 + y^2) $$
multipy both sides by $(x^2 + y^2)$
$$ (x^2 + y^2) k^2 = (d-x)^2 + y^2 $$
expand
$$ k^2 x^2 + k^2 y^2 = d^2 - 2 d x + x^2 + y^2 $$
gather $x$ and $y$ terms
$$ (k^2 - 1) x^2 + 2 d x + (k^2 - 1) y^2 = d^2 $$
divide through by $k^2 - 1$
$$ x^2 + { 2 d x  \over k^2 - 1 } + y^2 = { d^2 \over k^2 - 1 } $$
complete the square by adding $(d / (k^2 - 1))^2$ to both sides
$$ x^2 + { 2 d x  \over k^2 - 1 } + {d^2 \over \left (k^2 - 1 \right)^2} + y^2 = { d^2 \over k^2 - 1 } + {d^2 \over \left (k^2 - 1 \right)^2} $$
simplify the $x$ terms, and put the right hand side over a common denominator
$$ \left( x + { d \over k^2 - 1 } \right) ^2 + y^2 = { d^2 (k^2 - 1) + d^2 \over \left( k^2 - 1 \right)^2 } $$
finally simplify the right hand side
$$ \left( x + { d \over k^2 - 1 } \right) ^2 + y^2 = \left( { k d \over k^2 - 1 } \right) ^2 $$

Note the connection to image charges is that since we have shown that this arrangement of $q_2$ and $q_1$ produces a sphere with $V=0$, this charge arrangement is equivalent to charge $q_1$ in the presences of a grounded conducting sphere.  So $q_2$ represents the image charge of $q_1$ in a conducting shpere.